# Python coding error, error is TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am consistently getting this error message in python 3.4.2,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.
```

(I must use this version), this is the accused line of the error:

```
User_input_string = int(input("What is the answer to", (Random_num + Operator + Random_num2)))
```

Comment: looks like operator is a string here.. you might want to use a string formatter.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add up integers and a string:

```
Random_num + Operator + Random_num2
```

You'd normally have to convert to a common type first, like a string:

```
str(Random_num) + Operator + str(Random_num2)
```

but you can also use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
User_input_string = int(input("What is the answer to {} {} {}".format(
    Random_num, Operator, Random_num2))
```

The latter gives you more flexibility in how the output string is formed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing those vars are not strings

```
(str(Random_num) + str(Operator) + str(Random_num2))
```